# AndroidAnnotations: @Rest annotation compile error

Tags: android, spring, rest, android-annotations

When trying to define a rest template using the @Rest annotation, and when providing one or more "converters" in that annotation, I receive the following compile error:

`The converter class must be a subtype of org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter`

When, in fact, I have tried to pass in `GsonHttpMessageConverter.class` and `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class` which are both such subtypes.

I have the following libraries included in my `/libs` directory

```
androidannotations-api-2.7.1.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar
spring-android-auth-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with AndroidAnnotations or with my own setup, but help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code of your @Rest class.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I solved it. Only change my Eclipse. I was using Helios with Android Development Toolkit

Now I dowload [The Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) than includes Eclipse + ADT plugin. Use my old workspace with my proyect and all work fine!!!.

Comment: Sorry...now its better.

Answer (score 0):

Hello **its too late for answer but could be helpfull for others** also who are searching for the same use **Below code snippets for your problem:-**

```
@Rest(rootUrl =  BASE_URL, converters = {ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.class,
    FormHttpMessageConverter.class, StringHttpMessageConverter.class})
```

- it is working for image as well and string params as well